# Как получить и изменить переменную из QML в C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Пишу программу в Qt и возникла такая проблема, не понимаю как мне в C++ изменять значение переменных которые в qml были созданы. У меня есть C++ класс в котором есть кнопка которая вызывается из qml и в нее передаются определенные данные из qml а как мне в этой кнопке получать доступ к другим переменным и менять их?

Вот кнопка в C++:

```
#include "program.h"
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlProperty>


void program:: buttonClicked(int amount, int group, QString currency,bool type) {
qDebug() <<type;

Operations mid;
mid.setType(type);
mid.setGroup(group);
mid.setAmount(amount);
mid.setCurrency(currency);

operations.push_back(mid);

QObject* listViewer = viewer->findChild<QObject*>("theList");
QObject* listViewer2 = viewer->findChild<QObject*>("button2Invoke");



//Пробовал вот так:

QQuickView view;
view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("../moneyControl/main.qml"));
view.show();
QObject *object = view.rootObject();
QQmlProperty p(object, "currency");
qDebug()<<p.read();
//Но получаю ошибку:
//QQuickView does not support using windows as a root item. 

//If you wish to create your root window from QML, consider using QQmlApplicationEngine instead. 
}
```

Есть какой то способ сделать это так же просто как и получать всякие кнопки и лейблы из qml? по типу:

```
Object* listViewer = viewer->findChild<QObject*>("theList");
```

Comment: если это просто переменная, то сложно. Но если сделать эту переменную свойством в qml, то все возможно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541846/how-to-print-a-list-of-custom-properties-of-a-qml-object

Comment: @KoVadim Честно говоря там не особо понял как переконвертировать переменную в свойство.. можете подсказать?